# how to use ngFor in angular2 formControl

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I try to use formcontrolName bind the json data from the ngFor, but I don't know how to bind it. My way is not working,anyone has any idea?

```
  <p *ngFor="let user of searchuser" formControlName="username">{{user.username}}</p>
  <p *ngFor="let tool of searchtool" formControlName="rfidCode">{{tool.rfidCode}}</p>
```

Comment: Please provide information about the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
  <p *ngFor="let user of searchuser;let idx=index" formControlName="username{{idx}}">{{user.username}}</p>
  <p *ngFor="let tool of searchtool;let idx=index" formControlName="rfidCode">{{tool.rfidCode + idx}}</p>
```

`formControlName` needs to be unique but I would need more information about your actual requirements to make more concrete suggestions.

BTW: `formControlName` is for input elements, not for `<p>` elements.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControlName-directive.html